# Reporting services expression using Switch

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I couldn't get this expression working with reporting services. I have to use IF and ELSE IF statement. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
= Switch( IsNothing(Fields!field_date.Value),"", Fields!set_flag.Value=1,"Declined", Fields!field_name.Value)
```

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
If(IsNothing(Fields!field_date.Value)) Then "";

ElseIf Fields!set_flag.Value=1 Then "Declined";

Else Fields!field_name.Value
```

Comment: What error do you get with the switch statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't SSRS use the VB Runtime Library? In which case, the switch statement is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.switch.aspx) and states that you must have an **even** number of elements passed in.  If this is your issue, you're probably getting an `ArgumentException` thrown.

If you want to have a default return value, you'd have to add a dummy condition that always evaluates to true:

```
= Switch( IsNothing(Fields!field_date.Value),"", Fields!set_flag.Value=1,"Declined", True, Fields!field_name.Value)
```

Comment: It's not throwing any error. I can still see the field name is displayed even though set_flag = 1.

Comment: The syntax is correct as I have just tried it myself.  Is your set_flag value definitely an integer?

Comment: It's bit data type in the database.

Comment: If I use set_flag.Value = "1", it's working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a code block like gbn suggested.  It will be easier to read.  Here is a how to from Microsoft about used code blocks in Reporting Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

If you don't want to use a code block then you can chain IIF statements in your expression.  Looking at your example it would be something like

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!field_date.Value),"",IIF(Fields!set_flag.Value=1,"Declined",Fields!field_name.Value)
```

Any more than 2 IIF or anything more complex than just return a value, then I would definitely go for a code block.  Otherwise you are just making it that much worse for the person who has to maintain the report after you.