# Switch statement for multiple colour choices in pie chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, bids, pie-chart

Using SSRS BIDS 2008 to create a Pie Chart in one of my reports.

What is the syntax of the statement I need to type into the Expression box to specify which colours I would like each particular field of the pie chart to be.

The value i need to specify different colours for is 'value2' and their are a total of 4 possible values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you ENTIRELY SURE that the if statement predicate is correct?

It looks to me like "1.Proposal" is possibly a series label?

Comment: Youve nailed it, my problem was that 1.Proposal should have actually read as 1. Proposal - I was missing a space, thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Answered a question on this yesterday!  See [Reporting services expression using Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996571/reporting-services-expression-using-switch/7996863#7996863) for the Switch syntax.  Make sure you give it an even number of arguments.

Edit following your sample code - it should be `Switch` rather than `SWITCH`.  Check the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.switch.aspx).

Comment: It has an even number of arguments, still not working, this is what I have so far...

=SWITCH(
Fields!status2.Value="1.Proposal","Green",
Fields!status2.Value="2.Live","Red",
Fields!status2.Value="3.On Hold","Khaki",
Fields!status2.Value="5.Cancelled","Plum")

Comment: Updated answer following your sample code.  If it's still not working, an error message would be useful.

Comment: No error message, run the report and it just displays the bog standard colours from before, not my specified ones...

Comment: What if you add a final catch-all condition with a unique colour like this: `..., True, "Pink")` - then you'll at least know that the expression is being evaluated when it all goes pink!